# Unable to update ParentItemID while creating sharepoint discussion board reply using SP services

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I am trying to create reply to a Sharepoint discussion board discussion using list.asmx service, reply is getting populated but its corresponding ParentItemID is not getting updated.
Below is the code I am using:

```
 var promise = $().SPServices({ 
 operation: "UpdateListItems", 
 batchCmd: "New", 
 listName: list,       
 updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' RootFolder='" + filepath + "'>" +  
 "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" + 
 "<Field Name='ContentType'>Message</Field>" + 
 "<Field Name='FSObjType'>0</Field>" + 
 "<Field Name='Body'>Great Post</Field>" +     
 "</Method>" + 
"</Batch>" 
 });
```

Usually when we create reply form SharePoint UI , ParentItemID for a reply gets automatically populated.
I can't use SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply method.
Have to do this using REST api or list.asmx service.
Using REST I am only able to create discussions but not the replies.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it to work if I specify the "ParentItemID" field in the CAML.  I also made sure the "RootFolder" attribute uses the "FileRef" field retrieved for the parent discussion.

```
var promise = $().SPServices({
    operation : "UpdateListItems",
    batchCmd : "New",
    listName : list,
    updates : "<Batch OnError='Continue'" + 
       "RootFolder='MySite/Lists/My Discussion Forum/My Discussion Title'>" +
    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
    "<Field Name='ContentType'>Message</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='ParentItemID'>51</Field>" + 
    "<Field Name='FSObjType'>0</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Body'>Great Post</Field>" +
    "</Method>" +
    "</Batch>"
});
```

Comment: Hi Shelly,
Thank you for your response,I already tried the same, but it is not working for me.
I have updated my question with the result screenshot.

Comment: @Rooney123 Note: You have tried to edit Shellys answer with your screenshot and not your question.

Comment: @Daniel, by mistake I did that. Have rectified it now.

Comment: Yep, realized that. That is why I told you!

Comment: @shelly : It is still not working for me,any suggestions?

Comment: @Rooney123 Did you catch that the last segment of the RootFolder attribute is the Title of the discussion?

Comment: @Shelly : yes, I properly declared the RootFolder path , but still not able to get it work :(

Comment: Any help on this?? anyone?